# What does a dollar sign mean in a METAR?

Tags: weather, metar

Look at this METAR:

`KLOU 151553Z 21005KT 10SM CLR 13/M01 A3044 RMK AO2 SLP309 T01281011 $`

What does the dollar sign mean?

Comment: It means that they need to spend some money to fix whatever is broke on the automated reporting station!

Comment: @RalphJ That's actually a great mnemonic!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> A maintenance indicator sign, $, is included when an [ASOS/AWSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_airport_weather_station) (Automated Surface Observing System / Automated Weather Sensor System) detects that maintenance is needed on the system.

Reference: http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/JO%207900.5C.pdf

Or if you need an easy way to remember it, courtesy of the awesome Ralph J:

> It means that they need to spend some money to fix whatever is broke on the automated reporting station!

Comment: To improve the answer, it would be nice if you could resolve the ASOS and AWSS abbreviations, please.

Comment: ASOS = Automated Surface Observing System; AWSS = Automated Weather Sensor System. These are nicely described at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_airport_weather_station

Comment: Another appropriate reference for this would be the "Aviation Weather Services" advisory circular.