# Use of a METAR when $ is present

Tags: metar

I fly out of an uncontrolled airport that has an unmanned, automated weather reporting site with a precipitation sensor (AO2).  The METAR often has a \$ symbol at the end of the report, indicating that maintenance is needed on the equipment.  Can I use this METAR, or any METAR with a "\$" as a reliable indication of the current weather?

Comment: Related: [What does a dollar sign mean in a METAR?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/22944/3201)

Answer (score 0):

Do the indications match up and make sense compared with indications of a nearby airfield and other weather sources?

Legally the FARs require that pilots obtain "all available information" (FAR 91.103). $ could mean a number of things and since Metars are still available, you should be able to trust them, but I recommend to check more then one source regardless.